# Good Accuracy + Low Val_loss but very bad predictions

Tags: python-3.x, keras, classification, confusion-matrix

Going straight to the problem...

I am using Keras flow_from_directory to load the data for sound classification. Data_generator without any augmentation and shuffle =True and although most of my models have a very good accuracy (92%) and a small val_loss the confusion matrix shows that the model is not predicting the labels correctly

I have tried simple models and complex models with keras flow_from_directory and data_generator on UrbanSound8k dataset. Also tried batch normalization, bias and kernel regularizers to avoid overfitting.

The results look almost random.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide some examples of your code? Doing so might yield more views and a faster answer to your question.

Comment: You are asking a question about **data mining**, but where is the **Data**? You got to show the summary statistics of the data so that folks can relate to the problem better.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. There are a million things that can result as your problem. So without code and specific understanding of the network no-one can help you. We need to see the code for better understanding!!

Comment: Guys, I found out eventually what was the problem! Although it took hours...to notice my mistake... I was using image data generator from Keras to feed the data. And on the testing dataset I accidentally left the shuffle = True. Of course when I changed to False everything was working properly.